# does a zero fill format "heal" a drive?

Tags: formatting

I have an old Maxtor hard disk with problems on its blocks, I've run the seatools for dos tool and it' ve found several back blocks.

I launched a zero fill format from seatools, then redo a short test and this time, the hdd passed it, my question is: is the hard drive reliable now ? I don't mean to save very important files on it, but I wonder if I run the risk to power on the pc in a week and see the hard drive is not recognized from BIOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those particular blocks were marked as bad by the drive when it couldn't write zeroes to them.  So, in that sense, yes, that problem is resolved and the drive won't try to write to those blocks again.

However, odds are there may be more bad blocks in your future.  It's safe to use the drive for non-critical stuff, but understand that you may run into the same problem again.

Answer (score 4):

If it has had the kind of problems you describe, I wouldn't use it for anything at all critical.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, I have repaired bad sectors using the GRC Spinrite program....then I get as much information off as quickly as possible.  In one case, the disk was actually ok for a couple of years.